# Run workflow when a configuration file has changed or source code has changed

Tags: github, dependencies, github-actions

My objective is to automate the creation of new versions of docker images when one or more dependencies are changed. We are using Nuget [Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) for our repositories.

In our configuration we have:

1. One github repository (let's call it **Dependency Updater**) that contains officially used dependency and some other files, e.g. `Directory.Packages.props`, `global.json`, among others.
2. Multiple github repositories which represents class libraries, web apis and web apps.

When a dependency changes occur we update the files contained in the *Dependency Updater* repository and a sync github action is triggered that update other repos. The sync action pushes new dependencies files into each of the effective repos

```
name: Default files Sync
on:
  workflow_dispatch: # Allow running the workflow manually from the GitHub UI
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  file_sync:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          lfs: 'true'
      - name: File sync
        uses: kbrashears5/github-action-file-sync@v2.0.0
        with:
          REPOSITORIES: |
            my_org/repo_1@main
            my_org/repo_2@main
          FILES: |
            config/dotnet-tools.json=.config/dotnet-tools.json
            tools/packages.config=tools/packages.config
            Directory.Build.props=Directory.Build.props
            Directory.Packages.props=Directory.Packages.props
            global.json=global.json
            [... other files omitted for brevity ...]
          TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PACKAGES_SECRET }}
```

This action works nice and in effect pushes the changed files into each of the listed repos. The effective repos to release, in turn, are configured with a Release github action which is like this one (I will only enumerate the steps for brevity)

```
name: Release Action

on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - src/**
      - tests/**
      - Directory.Package.props
      - [...other files omitted for brevity...]
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
    permissions:
      contents: write
      checks: write
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
      - name: Adjust NuGet Config Credentials
      - name: Restore packages
      - name: Install GitVersion
      - name: Determine Version
      - name: Display GitVersion outputs
      - name: Build Application
      - name: Run Unit Tests
      - name: Publish Test Results
      - name: Generate code coverage report
      - name: Add Coverage Comment
      - name: Create and push Tag
      - name: Create Release
      - name: Docker Setup Buildx
      - name: 'Login to Container Registry'
      - name: Docker pull to cache image
      - name: Set up QEMU
      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
```

As you can see we are using Github paths filter to only run the action when one of two conditions occur:

- A source file has changed, either in `src` or `tests` folder
- A dependency file has changed

However, when the new dependency are pushed into each of the effective repositories, the `Release action` does not trigger at all.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you expand on not working as expected? Per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore it triggers if any file matches a path, so it's already an "or".

Comment: It does not trigger at all. Please consider, if this is important that the push on these files is made by another github action and not manually

Comment: If you're just using the default token that _deliberately_ does not trigger additional workflows per https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication, https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27028

Comment: No. I am using an organization secret which has permissions to read and create packages. Is there any other permission that I need to enable on the token and/or in the workflow?